# My NSUserDefaults code does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

When I try to use `NSUserDefaults` on two different screens, the `NSUserDefaults` does not apply and there is not an error that comes up.  Basically, I want the next level to be available only after the first one is completed.

Here is my code:

View1:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {      
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger level1Complete = [prefs integerForKey:@"levelComplete"];

    if (level1Complete == 11) {
        button2.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

View2:

```
if (number11 == 5) {

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:11 forKey:@"levelComplete"];

    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

Please note: the game play itself is view2 and the level select is view1.

Comment: Is this a question? I don't see a question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"11" forKey:@"levelComplete"];
```

if you can save it as a value and when you fetch it then convert it into integer.

All The Best!!